# Multiplayer version of Quizl

Tags: quizl

I recently started playing [David Parlett's Quizl](https://www.parlettgames.uk/wgames/quizl.html). It's a word game that is something like a cross between a word search and Battleship, and I really enjoy it. It's a two-player game, but I was wondering if anyone has adapted it for more players, along the same lines as multiplayer Battleship or Salvo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An update to the website in October 2014 added rules for a multiplayer version of Quizl:

> ### Quizl for three or more
>
> Quizl works perfectly well for three or more, apart from the hassle of having to draw a check-grid for each opponent, so it's best to have them pre-printed. Each player in turn calls out a grid reference, as before, but you have to get used to the fact that when you call one, you do not reveal the letter you have placed in that cell of your own grid. If somebody wants to know what you have in it, they will have to make the same call, even though they will learn nothing new about the others in that turn.

Answer (score 1):

I've not seen any multiplayer versions before, but why couldn't you play this the same way that you play multiplayer battleships?

I've played a few variations of multiplayer battleships. One where you select a square in a single opponent's grid, another where all shots hit all grids.  I've even played a version where your shots hit all opponent's grids, but not your own (which made it very tempting to shoot at your own ships).

Players would score for guessing a password as in the original game.  You could implement a score penalty for an incorrect guess, otherwise there would be significantly less benefit in revealing an opponent's square.

If you want to enlarge the search space (for example, if playing that all shots hit all grids) then each player could create several 5x5 grids, only one of which contains a five letter word.

Answer (score 0):

There is a single-player version available [here](http://www.ericsolomon.co.uk/qz/quizl.html).  However, I do not believe it's available in a multiplayer version anywhere.